# Is this question well-defined? What is the probability of randomly selecting a real function that contains 0 in its range from $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, set-theory

**What is the probability of randomly selecting a real function that contains 0 in its range from $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ ?**

Suppose there were a theoretical machine that spits out a random real function chosen "uniformly randomly" from $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ . If we were to run the machine $n$ times, what is the expected number of times the machine will output a function with 0 in its range?

The problem I see here is that the size of the sample space, the size of the event set containing the real functions with 0 in their range, and the size of the complement of the event set are all ${2^\aleph_0}^{2^\aleph_0}$ . There's no clear way I can see to compare the relative sizes of these sets.

Moreover, I think "uniformly randomly" might be ambiguously defined because there may be multiple ways to randomly generate a real function that can be considered "uniformly random", yet arrive at different probabilities for each.

My background is an introductory statistics course (not rigorous) and set theory.

Comment: There are probability distributions on function spaces, but there is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$

Comment: So the question is ill-posed then?

Comment: Yes, for several reasons.  Even if you patched that one, it wouldn't be clear that something like $\{f : \exists a, f(a) = 0\}$ is an event without first specializing the function space.  Could you give the source for the question?

Comment: Sorry, I came up with it with limited rigorous probability theory knowledge, which is why I thought it might be ill-posed.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Do you have a reference discussing "uniform measures" on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$? For example, there is no uniform measure on $\mathbb N$, in the sense that $\mu(\{a\})=\mu(\{b\}$ for all $a,b$ is trivial, but showing that there is no measure such that $\mu(k\mathbb N)=1/k$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$ is harder. Admittedly, arbitrary countable sets do not have such a structure for a different notion of uniform like the naturals do. I guess I'm asking the same question for $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$. One could imagine something analogous, say the functions with codomain $[-r,r]$.

Comment: Im guessimg the same argument will work, but there could also be other natural ways of thinking about a "uniform" measure on said function space

Comment: @AndrewZhang Are you asking for a reference to support my claim there is no uniform measure on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$?  ... or my claim there are probability distributions on some function spaces?